# Type declaration with and

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

What is benefit of type declaration:

```
type xxx
and yyy
```

over

```
type xxx
type yyy
```

To give it semantic that one depends on another?

I'm using [OcamlWin 4.0](http://caml.inria.fr/download.en.html) and the code is from `C:\OCaml\lib\hashtbl.ml`

```
  type ('a, 'b) t =
  { mutable size: int;                        (* number of entries *)
    mutable data: ('a, 'b) bucketlist array;  (* the buckets *)
    mutable seed: int;                        (* for randomization *)
    initial_size: int;                        (* initial array size *)
  }

and ('a, 'b) bucketlist =
    Empty
  | Cons of 'a * 'b * ('a, 'b) bucketlist
```

it compiles. When I change the `and` to `type`

```
type ('a, 'b) t =
  { mutable size: int;                        (* number of entries *)
    mutable data: ('a, 'b) bucketlist array;  (* the buckets *)
    mutable seed: int;                        (* for randomization *)
    initial_size: int;                        (* initial array size *)
  }

type ('a, 'b) bucketlist =
    Empty
  | Cons of 'a * 'b * ('a, 'b) bucketlist
```

compiles as well.

Comment: I'd be surprised if it really worked. What could be accepted by OCaml would be `type bucketlist = ... ;; type t = ...` since, as remarked by Andreas Rossberg `bucketlist` does not depend on `t`. `type t = ... ;; type bucketlist = ...`  can only be accepted if there is already a `bucketlist` defined in the environment (e.g. if you evaluated the mutually recursive version in the interpreter and afterwards the non-recursive one in the same session).

Answer (score 3):

The `and` keyword is often used when defining mutually recursive declarations

Given your example

```
type ('a, 'b) t =
    { mutable size: int;                        (* number of entries *)
      mutable data: ('a, 'b) bucketlist array;  (* the buckets *)
      mutable seed: int;                        (* for randomization *)
      initial_size: int;                        (* initial array size *)
    }

type ('a, 'b) bucketlist =
    Empty
  | Cons of 'a * 'b * ('a, 'b) bucketlist
```

would give an `Error: Unbound type constructor bucketlist` on line 3, characters 20-39. However changing the second type with an and will remove the error.

```
type ('a, 'b) t =
    { mutable size: int;                        (* number of entries *)
      mutable data: ('a, 'b) bucketlist array;  (* the buckets *)
      mutable seed: int;                        (* for randomization *)
      initial_size: int;                        (* initial array size *)
    }

and ('a, 'b) bucketlist =
    Empty
  | Cons of 'a * 'b * ('a, 'b) bucketlist
```

I can't come up with a reason why it would compile for you in both cases, however if you were using the interpreter and you forget to close it down, then it will have old bindings in its environment.
That is, if you have first evaluated you code with the `and` keyword then you can keep re-evaluating the code without as `bucketlist` have already been defined in the invironment.

Comment: Hashtbl from standard library `type ('a, 'b) t = ....mutable data: ('a, 'b) bucketlist array; ... and ('a, 'b) bucketlist =
    Empty
  | Cons of 'a * 'b * ('a, 'b) bucketlist` just t depends on bucketlist

Comment: His example is from the OCaml standard library.

Comment: @lukas, first of all, sorry that I totally missed that this was a ocaml question. I just saw the ml tag and made assumptions from that :). However I have update my answer

Comment: @Jesper.Reenberg no need to apology. You are right. `ocamlc` doesn't compile. The answer is "It is used when one declaration depends on another (don't have to be mutually recursive).

Comment: @lukas, well if it was the case (as here) that it is only the first that depends on the second, then you could just as well switch the order of definition and there would be no need for it. So, you are right that it doesn't have to be mutually recursive definitions, but it does allow it. If you don't add this to the definition of the keyword, then it is just a pointless keyword.

Answer (score 2):

The `and` keyword is needed to express mutually recursive definitions. For example,

```
type t = A | B of u
and  u = C | D of t
```

would no longer compile if you were to replace `and` with `type`. In your example, its use is redundant, though.